# Constructor overloading in Singleton doesn't work

Tags: c++, singleton, destructor, constructor-overloading

I'm learning to use the Singleton design pattern. I wrote a simple code, include constructor overloading and a terminate function to delete the pointer. The problem is the constructor overloading doesn't work, it doesn't take 2 parameters. I can't figure out why?

```
//header============================================
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class singleton
{
public:
        static singleton* getInstance();
        static singleton* getInstance(int wIn,int lIn);
        static void terminate();// memmory management
        int getArea();// just to test the output


private:
        static bool flag;
        singleton(int wIn, int lIn);
        singleton();
        static singleton* single;
        int width,len;
};

//implement=============================
#include "singleton.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int singleton::getArea(){
        return width*len;
}
singleton* singleton::getInstance(int wIn,int lIn){

        if (!flag)
        {
                single= new singleton(wIn,lIn);
                flag= true;
                return single;
        }
        else
                return single;
}

singleton* singleton::getInstance(){
        if (!flag)
        {
                single= new singleton;
                flag=true;
                return single;
        }
        else
        {
                return single;
        }
}

void singleton::terminate(){

        delete single;
        single= NULL;
        perror("Recover allocated mem ");
}


singleton::singleton(int wIn,int lIn){

        width= wIn;
        len= lIn;
}

singleton::singleton(){
        width= 8;
        len= 8;
}
//main=======================================
#include <iostream>
#include "singleton.h"

bool singleton::flag= false;
singleton* singleton::single= NULL;

int main(){

        singleton* a= singleton::getInstance();
        singleton* b= singleton::getInstance(9,12);
        cout << a->getArea()<<endl;
        //a->terminate();
        cout << b->getArea()<<endl;
        a->terminate();
        b->terminate();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fair warning, singletons are an anti-pattern.

Comment: The whole point of a singleton is that you can only create one object. I doesn't make a sense to have a singleton with a constructor that takes arguments, because that implies you could create multiple objects with different parameters. I think you don't understand what a singleton is for. Maybe what you really want is the factory pattern?

Comment: Define: ***"Doesn't work"***

Comment: compiles and runs well with g++ 4.4.7, output:  64
64
Recover allocated mem : Success
Recover allocated mem : Success

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 64ms)

Comment: @john: Only one *at a time* can also be an option (for those that believe that a singleton is an option in the first place). I would not use the arguments in the `getInstance()` function anyway, but that is a different issue (in the same way that the implementation is not thread safe or that the `bool` flag is unneeded...

Comment: My bad ! John's right.  I read this http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1459/
then forgot what Singleton is for. Silly me :(

Comment: I'm using VS 2008 and can compile and run the code. If you can't compile it, try add `#include<stdio.h>` in the implement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your main function you do

```
singleton* a= singleton::getInstance();
```

so the instance is set to the value the singleton got from the empty constructor. then you do

```
singleton* b= singleton::getInstance(9,12);
```

but you forgot that `flag` is true because you set it to true in the empty constructor. so this line is meaningless.

after that, everything you do on b is the same as it was if you did it on a, so it doesn't work as you wanted

Comment: No Idea: This is what the OP wrote, so this is what we expect its behaviour should be.

Comment: @computer nice name, why compilation error? it's all good code, just expectation of one thing while getting something else...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: I'm assuming that the OP meant to set the `flag` in both constructors, so no line of code is meaningless, but might not do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` function interleaves the 'construction' and destruction of the singleton.

I'm not sure what you expected, but if the two pointers `a` and `b` were separated you would get a different output.

As it is both `a` and `b` point to the same object and so calls to `getArea()` will return the same result.

Comment: I understand my mistake and what you mean, but actually the `b->getArea()` return different value than `a->getArea()` , which is quite weird. 
Here is [**the console**](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7399/9588846395_16baaba680_o.png)

Comment: @Tiana987642: That's odd. I compiled your code (http://ideone.com/duY2kq) and it worked as I was expecting.

Comment: Yeap, I can't figure out why mine is weird? You know, if `a->getArea() ` and `b->getArea()` returned the same value, I could recognize my mistake sooner...

Comment: Argh, I call `terminate()` right after `a->getArea()`. That's the reason. Thank you !

Comment: Yes, it looks like your second call to `getArea()` calls an uninitialised instance of `singleton`.